# If statement failing due to unrelated change to another IF statement

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, contacts

When the check against the emailaddress is added to the if statement, as per below, the if statement `if (origin.Equals(true))`.

```
bool origin = false;
                    Contact contact = item as Contact;
                    foreach (Item subItem in contactItems)
                    {

                        Contact subcontact = subItem as Contact;

                        if ((contact.DisplayName.Equals(subcontact.DisplayName) || (contact.DisplayName is null && subcontact.DisplayName is null)) && ((contact.CompanyName is null && subcontact.CompanyName is null) || (contact.CompanyName.Equals(subcontact.CompanyName)) && ((contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1] is null && subcontact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1] is null) || (contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1].Equals(subcontact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1])))))
                        {
                            if (origin.Equals(true))
                            {

                                try
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(contact.DisplayName + " " + subcontact.DisplayName);
                                    Console.WriteLine(contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1]);
                                    subcontact.Delete(DeleteMode.HardDelete);

                                }
                                catch
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Cannot delete" + " " + subcontact.DisplayName);

                                }
                            }
                            origin = true;
                        }
                    }
```

If I remove the `if (origin.Equals(true))` or removed `&& ((contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1] is null && subcontact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1] is null) || (contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1].Equals(subcontact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1]))` from the other if statement, the contact goes through the try-catch block.

Can anyone see why?

Comment: OT why `if (origin.Equals(true))` instead of simply `if (origin)`?

Comment: Your condition is unreadable. Factor that out and I am confident you'll find the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the potential answers unfortunately they didn't fix the issue, the code is much easier to read though! In the end I separated the email address check to another IF statement which seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((contact.DisplayName.Equals(subcontact.DisplayName) || (contact.DisplayName is null && subcontact.DisplayName is null)) && ((contact.CompanyName is null && subcontact.CompanyName is null) || (contact.CompanyName.Equals(subcontact.CompanyName)) && ((contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1] is null && subcontact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1] is null) || (contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1].Equals(subcontact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1])))))
```

should be:

```
    if ((contact.DisplayName.Equals(subcontact.DisplayName) || (contact.DisplayName is null && subcontact.DisplayName is null) 
&& ((contact.CompanyName is null && subcontact.CompanyName is null) || (contact.CompanyName.Equals(subcontact.CompanyName)) 
&& ((contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1] is null && subcontact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1] is null) || (contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1].Equals(subcontact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1])))
```

the problem as I can see, is in the amount of ( ) you use, which I believe is incorrect.

Try to clean up your if statements to prevent these types of mistakes from happening, since this one was pretty long, and a few of your parenthesis are unnecessary

**EDIT**:
I tried running some code and it works. I did make some mistakes in the sample of the IF statement I mentioned above.. Maybe try copying my code, and substituting your specific code into it. It should work this way.

```
    public static void Main()
{
    bool origin = false;

    int[] t = {0,4,6,8,5,6,4,5};

    foreach(int i in t){
         if ((true || (true && true)) // if ((contact.DisplayName.Equals(subcontact.DisplayName) || (contact.DisplayName is null && subcontact.DisplayName is null)) 
            && ((true && true) || (true)) // && ((contact.CompanyName is null && subcontact.CompanyName is null) || (contact.CompanyName.Equals(subcontact.CompanyName))) 
            && ((true && true) || (true))) // && ((contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1] is null && subcontact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1] is null) || (contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1].Equals(subcontact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1])))))
        {
            if (origin.Equals(true))
            {

                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("here");
                }
                catch
                {
                     Console.WriteLine("Cannot delete" );

                }
            }
            origin = true;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I have tidied the IF state up but unfortunately I am still having the same issue.

Comment: I edited my answer a bit, hopefully that works for you!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a little Helper:

```
private bool EqualOrBothNull( string fromContact, string fromSubcontact )
{
    if ( fromContact == null && fromSubcontact == null ) return true;
    if ( fromContact != null && fromContact.Equals(fromSubcontact) ) return true;
    return false;
}
```

then you can use it like this:

```
if ( EqualOrBothNull( contact.DisplayName, subContact.DisplayName ) &&
     EqualOrBothNull( contact.CompanyName, subContact.CompanyName ) &&
     EqualOrBothNull( contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1],
                      subContact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1])
    )
{ 
   // ...

}
```

This increases readability and will make it easier to find the bug if any.